# Unity Error: MissingComponnetException with camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm tryinng to change the camera position by a GameManager script, but having an error like this:

> ```
> < MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "Game Manager" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
> You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "Game Manager". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. >
> ```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject maincamera;
    public void Awake () 
    {
        maincamera = GameObject.Find("Camera");
        maincamera.transform.position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what i get wrong and how can i fix this?

Comment: A more idiomatic way to get the camera may be to use `maincamera = Camera.main` (which is a [Unity-provided reference to the main camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)).

Comment: Yeah, I'm a idiot, Thanks you

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].